Trying to Access HttpContext in ActionFilterAttribute
So I was trying to access the httpContext accessor to fetch the jwt token claims , But when i try to fetch the claims in my custom authroize class its come out to be empty and its IsAuthenticated flag is false
The sample code
public class Authorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        // Get role ID from claims
        if (!int.TryParse(actionContext.HttpContext.User?.FindFirstValue("AcmRoleId"), out int roleId))
        {
            actionContext.Result = new ContentResult
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                Content = "Role ID not found in token"
            };
            return;
        }
}

THis is how i would be using this
[@Authorize(ModuleName = "Dashboard", Read = (int)ModulePrivileges.Own)]
I was expecting the HttpContext to contain the jwt token claims don't know why it don't contain any claim if their is a alternative let me know

You need to implement AuthorizeAttribute and IAuthorizationFilter for custom Authorization attribute. Such as following:
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _role;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role)
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        
        // Custom authorization logic
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !user.IsInRole(_role))
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}

Then you could use [CustomAuthorize("AcmRole")]
